# jQuery animate margin top

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate, margin

I have a script on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kX7b6/

**Nothing happens on hover**

On hover I want the green box to overlap the red box with a negative margin -50px. Nothing happens.

**The animation works, but not margin**

Just to show that the animation itself is working i added a opacity function to the animation. margin-top is set to 0px inline as far as I can see.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You had `MarginTop` instead of `marginTop`

http://jsfiddle.net/kX7b6/1/

It is also very buggy if you leave mid animation, here is update:

http://jsfiddle.net/kX7b6/3/

Note I changed it to `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` because I don't think the intention was to cancel the animation when you hover over the red or green area.

Answer (score 28):

use `'marginTop'` instead of `MarginTop`

```
$(this).find('.info').animate({ 'marginTop': '-50px', opacity: 0.5 }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 9):

check this same effect with *less* code

```
$(".item").mouseover(function(){
    $('.info').animate({ marginTop: '-50px' , opacity: 0.5 }, 1000);
});
```

[View recent fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sandeep/kX7b6/4/)

Comment: nice and pretty !

Answer (score 4):

`MarginTop` should be `marginTop`.

Answer (score 3):

```
$(this).find('.info').animate({'margin-top': '-50px', opacity: 0.5 }, 1000);
```

Not MarginTop. It works

Answer (score 1):

As said marginTop - not MarginTop.

Also why not animate it back? :)

See:
http://jsfiddle.net/kX7b6/2/

Answer (score 1):

i didn't know that the ".stop()" is necessary.

```
$(window).scroll(function () {

   var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
   console.log(scroll);

     if (scroll >= 50){
       $('.sidebar-padder').stop().animate({ 'height': '380px'}, 1000);
     }else{
       $('.sidebar-padder').stop().animate({ 'height': '600px'}, 1000);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

use the following code to apply some margin

```
$(".button").click(function() {
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(".scrolltothis").offset().top + 50;
  }, 500);
});
```

See this ans: [Scroll down to div + a certain margin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23472231/scroll-down-to-div-a-certain-margin)