# How to animate the adding of <br> with Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a page with images in an inline block that when clicked br tags and added before and after it so that the image is on its on line.

http://gyazo.com/ddfdd7da4d949ec48341b585d2495ab6

Here is a gif of what happens.

Is there anyway I can animate the movement of the divs?

Edit: Apologies I forgot to add my code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".imageFace").click(function(){
    id = $(this).attr('id');
    $(this).before("<br>");
    $(this).after("<br>")
});});
```

Comment: where is your code and jsfiddle?

Comment: How would like to animate?

Comment: So your appending <br> with jQuery. Can you please improve the quality of your question.

Comment: Attach CSS3 transitions to element you would like to transition in

Answer (score 1):

I assume by animating BR's, you want to animate pushing down content?  Rather than animate BR, you can use JQuery to animate the top margin, as in this example: [jQuery animate margin top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7806637/jquery-animate-margin-top)

Comment: or add a class that uses css3 transitions to animate the margin